# Pass URL Parameter to Mysql Query

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hopefully I can get some help with this.

I have a controller.php which queries a database to display a list of recent articles that have been added.

```
try    
{
  $recents = $pdo->query('SELECT id, blogtitle FROM article ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,6');
}

catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Error fetching blog posts: ' . $e->getMessage();
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
}
```

Within the same controller, I then loop through the data and store in an array:

```
foreach ($recents as $recent)
{
    $newest[] =  array ('id' => $recent['id'], 'blogtitle' =>  $recent['blogtitle']);
}
```

The same controller.php loads an article.html.php which displays the list of recent items as hyperlinks:

```
<section id="secondary">
    <h2 class="recent">Recent Posts</h2>
    <?php foreach ($newest as $new):?>
    <a href="article-detail.php?id=<?php echo htmlout($new['id']);?>"><?php echo htmlout($new['blogtitle']) . "</a>";?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</section>
```

As you can see I have appended the article ID to the url so it can get picked up and used to generate a mysql query for the particular blog article.

Again I have decided to get the same controller.php to load the article detail page with the particular article that pertains to the id that was passed in the url.

So controller.php checks to see if the id in the url isset, and if so, pass that id into a mysql query to retrieve the relevant article to the id:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
        include 'article-detail.php';
        exit();

        include  'dbinc/db.inc.php';
        include  'includes/magic.inc.php';

        try 
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT article.id, article.blogdate, article.blogtitle, article.blogtext, author.name 
            FROM article INNER JOIN author
            ON authorid = author.id
            WHERE article.id = :id';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id']);
            $s->execute();
        }
         catch (PDOException $e)
        {
          $error = 'Error fetching blog posts: ' . $e->getMessage();
          include 'error.html.php';
          exit();
        }

    while ($row = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
         $blogdate = $row['blogdate'];
         $blogtitle = $row['blogtitle'];
         $blogtext = $row['blogtext'];
         $authorname = $row['name'];
    }
```

}

Then the article-detail.php takes the $blogdate, title, text etc to display THAT specific article with standard html.  So as you can see I am trying to adhere to a controller/template model here.

However, going through this process when I click on any of the hyperlinks, the id is certainly getting passed in the URL, but I don't think the controller is picking up the id correctly and therefore NOT passing the id to the mysql query to retrieve the particular article?

Essentially, when I click one of the article links, the detail page does load but the $blogdate, $blogtext etc are undefined because I don't think the id is getting passed to the mysql query correctly?

So any help or advice as to where I'm going wrong much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: have you actually enabled exception mode on PDO? by default it just silently returns boolean false from failed calls, and won't throw exceptions. and have you checked if the query actually returns anything? Assuming that "get article details" query will only ever find one record, why are you using a loop to fetch any resulting rows?

Comment: And if this is the ACTUAL CODE you are trying, you are exiting the code right after loading the article page and never getting down to the DB querying part.

Comment: I've tried catching $_GET['id'] and assigning to an $id variable then in the detail page, echoing that $id variable, but nothing was getting passed.  Therefore not sure if its the way the id is originally getting passed in URL properly?

Comment: What is htmlout()? Also, your <a... is not terminated correctly.

Comment: Htmlout is a function the saves having to use htmlspecialchars.